# postgresql и тп: сколько может быть индексов (измерений)?

Tags: база-данных

Скажите, пожалуйста,в PostgreSQL и аналогичных БД(СУБД) таблицы всегда двумерные в виде листа екселя или могут быть трехмерные и тд?
(да, я пока новичок, а может и не пока)

Comment: В некоторых СУБД существуют так называемые _кубы_ (cube). [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/cube.html), [Sql Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scsm/olap-cubes-overview?view=sc-sm-2019)

Comment: спасибо, да, ну пока буду ориентироваться на простые, раз они точно везде есть